# Input numbers until 0, then calculate average

Tags: java, while-loop

Okey, i need to make a program to calculate average. But, i need to input numbers, and when i want to stop i can input zero. Then, my program need to sum all entered numbers and calculate average of entered numbers. I made almost everyithing in my code but idk how to make a formula to calculate average, my program sum numbers and then divide by last entered number.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input numbers, 0 for stop!");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int number1 = 1;
    while (number != 0) {
        number1 = (number + number1) / number; //here is my problem?
        number = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Average is: " + number1);
```

Comment: Why not sum all the numbers entered, and then outside the loop divide the sum by how many numbers were entered

Comment: I already tried that, but cant initialize variable outside loop and that is new problem. But thank you.

Comment: Maybe i made a mistake somewhere, i will try again. Okey i got it, sum all numbers and then divide, but how to divide by all entered numbers, for example, if i input 5 5 5 that is 15 and then 15 / 3, how to make 3 automatic?

Comment: Initialize `number` and then move the `while` statement to the top.

Comment: Sorry guys, can i input code in comment? No?

Comment: Besides, try giving variables meaningful names. number1 should be called average.

Comment: @DorianGray Sorry for that.

Comment: @SveZamene Its okay, it was just a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is written great except you calculate the average wrong,

If you want to calculate the average on the fly you will need to know how much numbers you have read so far..

e.g:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input numbers, 0 for stop!");
int number = input.nextInt();
int average = number;
int counter = 1;
while (number != 0) {
    average= (average * counter + number) / (counter + 1);
    counter++;
    number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
```

this code will give you the average after each step.

Another (simpler solution) is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input numbers, 0 for stop!");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    double sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        sum += number;
        counter++;
        number = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Average is: " + sum/counter);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem, I did not know how to enter how many numbers were entered. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Average is the sum total of the numbers divided by the number of numbers, so you need to keep a running count of how many numbers you are inputting, as well as a running sum, and at the end, you divide the sum by the count. The sum should be a double just in case you end up with a fraction

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input numbers, 0 for stop!");
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
int number = input.nextInt();
while (number != 0) {
    sum += number;
    count++;
    number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Average is: " + sum/count);
```

Comment: An explanation here would go a long way to explaining to the OP and subsequent viewers what your code does.